# How can I register a servlet filter to catch all HTTP requests in an OSGi container?

Tags: osgi, servlet-filters

I've got an OSGi container that hosts several CXF web services at /services/service_a; /services/service_b etc along with a couple of web apps deployed as bundles.  I'm trying to SSO enable all the endpoints but am having trouble registering a servlet filter with the Jetty server so I can have Spring Security take over.

Using Pax-web whiteboard I was able to register a filter tied to a simple servlet.  However, when I attempted to filter requests at /*, the filter no longer catches the requests.  Is it possible to register a filter that will catch all requests either using pax-web or some Jetty-osgi magic?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it's possible with the http whiteboard.

However you should be able to achieve the same end result using pax-web with Jetty's standard SSO management, by creating a fragment bundle.

Some links:

http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Single+Sign+On+-+Jetty+HashSSORealm

http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/SessionIds

http://team.ops4j.org/wiki/display/paxweb/Advanced+Jetty+Configuration

Comment: I'm actually looking to use JOSSO for SSO implementation so I need some way to register a servlet filter against my cxf endpoints.  The web apps, I can declare filters in web.xml, but the endpoints are using CXF bundle with no web.xml